# Error inflating class CollapsingToolbarLayout After Update Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio

I am getting an error inflating with `android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout`.

Before I updated Android Studio, it was working fine.

The error is:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 Process: com.ciputraresidence.ciapp.ourproject, PID: 22143
   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ciputraresidence.ciapp.ourproject/com.ciputraresidence.ciapp.ourproject.HomeActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #33: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5021)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:827)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:643)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #33: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
       at com.ciputraresidence.ciapp.ourproject.HomeActivity.onCreate(HomeActivity.java:44)
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5318)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1090)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5021) 
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:827) 
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:643) 
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696) 
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755) 
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758) 
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758) 
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758) 
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280) 
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
       at com.ciputraresidence.ciapp.ourproject.HomeActivity.onCreate(HomeActivity.java:44) 
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5318) 
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1090) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5021) 
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:827) 
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:643) 
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
    Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.support.v4.graphics.drawable.DrawableCompat.setLayoutDirection
       at android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout.setStatusBarScrim(CollapsingToolbarLayout.java:663)
       at android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout.<init>(CollapsingToolbarLayout.java:197)
       at android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout.<init>(CollapsingToolbarLayout.java:132)
       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) 
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594) 
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696) 
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755) 
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758) 
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758) 
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758) 
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280) 
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
       at com.ciputraresidence.ciapp.ourproject.HomeActivity.onCreate(HomeActivity.java:44) 
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5318) 
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1090) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5021) 
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:827) 
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:643) 
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is my XML layout:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".HomeActivity">

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            android:id="@+id/coordinator"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

                <!--<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />-->

                <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                    android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
                    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                        android:src="@drawable/image"
                        app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

                    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                        app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />

                </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

            </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/viewpager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
            app:menu="@menu/drawer"
            app:itemTextColor="@color/colorPrimary"/>

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>


    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tablayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/tabDefaultSelectedColor"
        app:tabGravity="center"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And the Gradle dependencies:

```
- testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
- compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
- compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
- compile('com.github.ozodrukh:CircularReveal:2.0.1@aar') {
     transitive = true;
}
- compile('com.mikepenz:fastadapter:1.6.2@aar') {
    transitive = true
}
- compile files('libs/androidasync-2.1.6.jar')
- compile files('libs/ion-2.1.6.jar')
- compile 'com.wang.avi:library:2.1.1'
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved by myself. With following this step by step:

- Upgrade / Update / Install SDK
- Change compile SDK version to 24 (API 24: Android 7.0 (Nougat))
- Change version of Android support library dependencies

  ```
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
  compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.0'
  ```
- Try to sync, or just debug/run your app on Android Studio.